# How do I return something (ArrayList to be precise) from an AsynTask class in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, global-variables

So I have a Fragment `x.java` and an AsyncTask Class BackgroundDataExtractor (As two separate java files). The fragment class contains this piece of code:

```
BackgroundDataExtractor backgroundWorker = new BackgroundDataExtractor(getActivity(),items);
backgroundWorker.execute(name);
```

Where the variable `items` is a global `ArrayList<CustomClass>` defined in class `x`.

I want the BackgroundDataExtractor class to add/update elements to `items` (which is located in the fragment `x`).

What I currently have is:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        if(!result.contains("Could not fetch items")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            String[] resultSplit = result.split(" ");
            for(int i=1; i<resultSplit.length; i++) {
                String[] tempStringArray = resultSplit[i].split(";");
                items.add(new itemClass(tempStringArray[1],tempStringArray[2],tempStringArray[6],tempStringArray[3],tempStringArray[4],Double.parseDouble(tempStringArray[7])));
            }
        }
        else {
            xxxxxx
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't update the `items` variable in the fragment `x`.

Any tips on how to get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't return something from asynchronous processes but you can call a function from `onPostExecute` and send the data you want. like this

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        //initiate vars
        public myTask() {
            super();
            //my params here
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //do stuff
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //do stuff
            myMethod(myValue);
        }
    }

    private void myMethod(Value myValue) {
         //handle value 
    }
}
```